# Where Can I find more or less detailed description of mobjects?

Tags: manim

Can you, please, refer me to a resource(s) where I can find list of attributes and methods for manim objects? (videos or sites, if there exist such). I tried to learn it myself by looking into mobject folder, but got to say, my brain got lost. I also tried looking in the Internet, didn't find much.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no complete documentation of Manim, the closest is [this](https://elteoremadebeethoven.github.io/manim_3feb_docs.github.io/html/tree/mobjects/mobjects.html) that I created (but its development is paused).

So, at the moment, there is no other way to learn without having to see the source code. Manim was not designed to be Open Source, Manim is simply the Grant Sanderson tool that he uses to make his videos, and he decided to share it, but he has no responsibility to document it, whoever wants to learn will have to understand the source code (at least for now).

I have tried to contribute with [my tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENMyFGmq5OA&list=PL2B6OzTsMUrwo4hA3BBfS7ZR34K361Z8F), but since Manim is constantly modified (for example, in the shaders branch, he no longer uses Pycario, but ModernGL) it is difficult to have useful documentation, since some things can work differently in a matter of months .

So for now, until someone is encouraged to do all the documentation work (which is quite a lot) we have no choice but to learn this way.

Comment: I'm following your tutorials to get a feeling of how manim works. They are excellent. Do you have plans to continue them, even with the constant updates that Grant is doing?

Comment: I hope to make the documentation in July of the most recent version, but from that date I will try to create my own animation tool, and once I get it I will do the tutorials on how to make "your own Manim" using C/C++ and Java (using Manim as a reference), so from the beginning of that project I will stop doing Manim tutorials. So I don't think I do tutorials for ModernGL version, only PyCairo's.