# Group manim TextMobjects into one animatable object?

Tags: python, manim

If I had 3 lines of manim text,

```py
l  = TextMobject("Line 1")
l2 = TextMobject("Line 2")
l3 = TextMobject("Line 3")
```

and I wanted to animate them all together, how would I do that? I'm looking for something easier to type and more pythonic than

```py
v = np.array([-3, 2, 0]) # Vector to translate the text by
self.play(ApplyMethod(l.shift, v), ApplyMethod(l2.shift, v), ApplyMethod(l3.shift, v))
```

Something more like:

```py
lines = [l, l2, l3]
g = GroupMobjects(*lines)
v = np.array([-3, 2, 0]) # Vector

self.play(ApplyMethod(g.shift, v))
```

Where I just made up the `GroupMobjects` syntax for the above example.

I've looked at using `VGroup`, and it seems like a good match for what I'm trying to accomplish, but the problem is that I have no clue how to use it, and manim doesn't have the best documentation (although for a [good reason](https://www.3blue1brown.com/faq#manim)).

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two types of containers in Manim, `Groups` and `VGroups`, the difference is that `VGroups` can only contain `VMobjects` (objects based on Bezier curves), whereas `Groups` can be of other types like Images (you cannot group images in `VGroups`, only in `Groups`).

As I have already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168384/where-can-i-find-more-or-less-detailed-description-of-mobjects), the complete documentation does not exist, only parts ([EulerTour](https://eulertour.com/docs) and [TB](https://elteoremadebeethoven.github.io/manim_3feb_docs.github.io/html/index.html)). If you want to learn how they are used, I can leave [this](https://github.com/Elteoremadebeethoven/AnimationsWithManim/blob/master/English/extra/faqs/faqs.md#arrange-objects) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfifBmYTEfA&t=116s) links, but in general, for now, you will have to learn from the [source code](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/mobject/mobject.py) (`VGroup` is a subclass of `VMobject`, and `VMobject` is a subclass of `Mobject`).